# What MIME type to choose for XML Schema 2

Tags: xml, http, xpath

I have an XML document containing lots of data entities, each data entity is to be returned over HTTP with an appropriate HTTP/1.1 Content-Type for that entity. The problem is that all the entities in the XML documents are stored with reference to their XML Schema, XQuery, and XPath data type. For example "-P13M" is stored with the type https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xpath-functions-20041029/#dt-yearMonthDuration for a defining a year-month, there are many more differnt kinds of data types. What HTTP/1.1 Content-Type or MIME type should I use when returning these entites via our HTTP endpoint?